# Hibernare Getting Max date from multiple table after INNER JOIN

Tags: hibernate

I have two following tables

**table 1**

```
ID |  HOTEL ID | NAME 
1       100      xyz 
2       101      pqr
3       102      abc
```

**table 2**

```
ID | BOOKING ID | DEPARTURE DATE | AMOUNT
1         1       2013-04-12        100
2         1       2013-04-14        120
3         1       2013-04-9          90
4         2       2013-04-14        100
5         2       2013-04-18        150
6         3       2013-04-12        100
```

I want the result as

```
ID | BOOKING ID | DEPARTURE DATE | AMOUNT
2         1       2013-04-14        120
5         2       2013-04-18        150
6         3       2013-04-12        100
```

How can I achieve this in hibernate query language. Preferably I would like to use hibernate .createQuery("").list()

Answer (score 0):

```
select table12.ID,table12.BOOKING_ID,table12.DEPARTURE_DATE,table12.AMOUNT from table2 table12 
where table2 table12 .BOOKING_ID IN (select distinct table22.BOOKING_ID
                      from table2 table22 
                      order by table22.DEPARTURE_DATE desc );
```

check for this and late me know.

Answer (score 0):

As per the your required resultset, you don't need to join it with hotel table as you can retrieve the necessary data from booking table it self.

You can try out the following hql(You may need to change the column names as per your requirement )

```
String hql = "(SELECT b.id, b.booking_id, MAX(b.amount), b.booking_date FROM Booking b GROUP BY b.booking_id)"
session.createQuery(hql).list();
```